# Text area shifted right slightly using geometry package

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, geometry

I've just discovered the `geometry` package, which seems like a nicer way of doing things than manually setting a bunch of lengths, and I'd like to set all my margins to 0.75in. I thought this would be easy enough: just input `\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}`. But something seemed a bit off; the text seemed a bit too far to the right. So I changed it to `\usepackage[margin=0.75in,centering]{geometry}`; still no change, everything was still shifted right. Here is a minimal working example - I've changed the margins to 0in, to emphasize the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,centering]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
test \hfill test
\vfill
test \hfill test
\vfill
test \hfill test
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Is there another option I need to set to get the text area to align correctly relative to the page?

I'm using TeXnicCenter on Windows 7, and outputting to PDF, if that helps.

Comment: @Jake: Ah, of course! Thanks. That's what I get for not trying a more substantive example, I guess :) If you want to make that an answer, you can, or I can just go ahead and delete this I guess.

Comment: I guess other people might stumble across this as well. I've made the comment an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just the paragraph indentation of the first line of each paragraph. If you put `\noindent` before the first `test`s of each line (or use a test text that's long enough to wrap around the line), you'll get the expected result.